# How to remove a file from Android's stock “Downloads” app?

Tags: android, download

Querying the DownloadManger appears to be the only way to retrieve a file ID and remove its reference in the stock "Downloads" app.  This is suggested in [Clear out android Downloads list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148564/clear-out-android-downloads-list).  I have been unable to make this work.

My app is privately distributed and updates itself whenever necessary. That works well, but I want to programmatically delete the update .apk file when the new version starts. The delete succeeds, but the file remains listed in Downloads. If the user taps on it, they receive a "Parse error" because it's obviously no longer there. Ugly...

I'd like to clean this up. Here's the relevant part of my code (which is called before the file is deleted):

```
public void DoCleanup(Context context) {

   DownloadManager oDM = (DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(android.content.Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
   Cursor oCur = oDM.query(new DownloadManager.Query().setFilterByStatus(o_DM.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL));

   if (oCur.getCount() > 0) {
      oCur.moveToPosition(-1);
      while (oCur.moveToNext()) {         
         if ( --some condition-- ) { 
            int iRemove = oDM.remove(oCur.getLong(oCur.getColumnIndex(oDM.COLUMN_ID)));            
         }
      }
   } 

}
```

oCur.getCount() is always 0 even if no filter is set on the query object. Why?  The file is definitely in the folder obtained from `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`.